# Button can only run "alert()" and not any other code

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

My button `<button id="btnDelete" class="delete-button" onclick="DeleteItems()">-</button>` in ejs and it can only run alert() codes and not the rest like console.log(). I have added `app.use(express.static("public"));` in my nodejs. this is my route for the js file in the header `<script src="\script\button.js"></script>`

This is what i want my button to do:

```
function DeleteItems(){
   const pagetitle = document.getElementById("ListTitle").innerHTML;
   let arr = [];
   let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
   if(checkboxes.length == 0){
        alert("Please check at least one checkbox to delete");
        return;
   }
   for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        arr.push(checkboxes[i].value);
   }
   let body = JSON.stringify({checked : arr});
   fetch("/remove",
        {method: "post",
        redirect:"follow",
        body: body,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json' 
        }})
        .then(response => {
            if(response.redirected){
                window.location.href = "/typeoflist/" + pagetitle;
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.info(err);
        });
}
```

I have tried testing the button to see if it worked with console.log and alert and it only displayed the alert command and not the console.log. it also does not route it into my post request ("/remove") in app.js.

Comment: I guess that means `checkboxes.length == 0` - have you tried `input[type=checkbox]:checked`

Comment: Oh yea i forgot to add that when I put the js code in my ejs file in the <script></script> tags, it works. and if i put console.log("Test") above the if statement it also does not print it out.

Comment: check the developer console for errors ... note `src="\script\button.js` looks like you're using the wrong `/`